# Can you or How can you make custom functions MongoDB like db.mydbname.customFunction()?

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql

I'd like to know if you could write custom functions in MongoDB similar to a stored procedure for queries?

Answer (score 7):

There aren't *exactly* stored procedures in MongoDB, but you can write Javascript functions that get stored in the DB (in the `system.js` collection).

Have a look at [this article](http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2010/08/getting-started-with-stored-procedures-in-mongodb.html) to get started.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special system collection named system.js that can store JavaScript functions for reuse.

NOTE:

> Do not store application logic in the database. There are performance
>   limitations to running JavaScript inside of MongoDB. Application code
>   also is typically most effective when it shares version control with
>   the application itself.

See [The Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/).